# Why do I keep getting a "Directory not empty" error in SSIS packages that aren't using File System Tasks?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, oledb

I am in charge of a Data Warehouse that is populated nightly from a database using SQL Server Integration Services. We have A TON of packages that run overnight to build out our DWH, the vast majority of which are just performing straightforward ETL processes so that we can effectively report on the data. 99.9% of the packages just read from and write to an OLEDB connection manager after performing the ETL stuff (mappings, calculations, etc).

The entire solutions, DTSX files, etc are all held on and run from the file system of the Windows Server where SQL Server is hosted.

Recently we moved from SQL Server 2012 up to SQL Server 2019 and quickly found that the majority of our packages didn't like running on this new platform. We had to run through all of them at update the 'TargetServerVersion' to target 2019 and 'TargetFrameworkVersion' to target .NET 4.7. Additionally we had to go through and rename EVERY script task that contained C# code too. Following those changes the jobs then seemed to mostly run okay each night, but we do keep getting this one intermittent issue that I just can't nail down...

Some mornings (not all) we get failures with the error "The directory is not empty. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070091)".

I have googled this extensively and everything I find points to packages that are running File System Tasks or code that refers to files/folders on the local machine. We are not doing this! We have one job with a File System Task and that one never fails! The failures we see are always on pure SQL jobs (as above- OLEDB in and out, that's all).

It seems the issue is always with a small handful of jobs - namely the ones that build out the Dimension and Fact tables - but they don't always fail. When it does fail I can simply re-run it in SSMS and it'll either fail again, or just succeed. There isn't any real rhyme or reason to it.

I am not formally trained to be a Data Warehouse engineer so I don't necessarily know what I might be missing here. I feel like I've tried everything to resolve this issue, but cannot get the bottom of it.

Is there anyone who can give me some new avenues to investigate?

Comment: With no details of where the package is failing, which will be explicitly explained in your SSISDB errors, and what that specific node is going, we can't help you. We can't see your environment, and we can't access your packages. An error on it's own doesn't mean anything to us. *You* need to do the initial debugging and then when you get stuck then explain that and give us ***all*** the details so we can elaborate on what's happening.

Comment: Hi Thom, can you advise what you mean by SSISDB errors? The only error I get is the one I put into my initial post above. These packages are not deployed to the server as integration packages, they run from the file system (also mentioned above). As I said I'm not formally trained in this stuff so I'm not sure what or how to debug specifically, I've looked in all the areas I know to find the root cause, so now I've come here. I'm looking for pointers for what else to look for. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using SSISDB? It's *far* better a deployment method and was introduced way back in 2012.

Comment: My predecessor created the DWH in it's current form, and I couldn't tell you why that decision was made, but I am only a temporary custodian really so cannot really make that change myself. I know it would be better deployed to the server. I would prefer it that way tbh...

Comment: Honestly, I haven't touched a file system deployed system since 2013, but *if* I recall my decade old memories, then the amount of information in the agent logs is far more limited. You'll probably need to run the problematic package in Visual Studio and get some more meaningful information from there. (Or better yet, change the deployment method and then you can make use of the *significantly superior* logging from SSISDB.)

Comment: Check Event View and the log files in the SQL Server.  You can get the log files by using SQL Server Management Studio in the explorer under Management.  Also check logging in SSIS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging?view=sql-server-ver16